# Slick: Autogenerate H2-DDL in Test case

Tags: playframework, h2, slick, play-slick

I'm using slick 2.0.0 in my application and in dev/prod, it is working fine.

In test mode, I want to autogenerate a H2 database (out of the slick table definitions) and use this for my test cases. I use scalatest 2.0.

The database definition (application.conf) for test is the following

```
db{
  ...
  test {
    driver=org.h2.Driver
    url="jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"
  }
}
```

At the beginning of a test case, I call

```
Slick.db.withTransaction { implicit s =>
  StaticQuery.updateNA("DROP ALL OBJECTS;")

  val createStatement = models.slick.Tables.ddl.createStatements.mkString("",";",";")
  println("CREATE: "+createStatement)
  StaticQuery.updateNA(createStatement)
}
```

(in test mode, Slick.db points to DB("test") from the play-slick plugin, so it simply takes the DataSource defined in application.conf in db.test)

When running the test case, I get the following output:

```
CREATE: [...]; create table `mytable` (`field1` VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,`field2` VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,`field3` VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,`ID` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY); [...]
[info] - should [...] *** FAILED ***
[info]   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Tabelle "MYTABLE" nicht gefunden
[info] Table "MYTABLE" not found; SQL statement:
[info] INSERT INTO `mytable` (`field1`,`field2`,`field3`) VALUES (?,?,?) [42102-172]
[info]   at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
[info]   at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
[info]   at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
[info]   at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:4824)
[info]   at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:4802)
[info]   at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsert(Parser.java:966)
[info]   at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:375)
[info]   at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:279)
[info]   at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:251)
[info]   at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:218)
[info]   ...
[info] ScalaTest
```

So it definitely creates the table and accesses the same table (though in upper case). Is case a problem? Don't think so. How can I make this work?

If case is a problem, is there a way to tell slick to either generate or use the tables with the same case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be

```
StaticQuery.updateNA(createStatement).execute
```

instead of

```
StaticQuery.updateNA(createStatement)
```